# c3.js total count in title of pie chart

Tags: sum, title, pie-chart, c3.js, donut-chart

I have a question about the pie chart in c3.js.

How can I add the total count of a pie chart in the title??

```js
  var title = new Array('data1.sql','data2.sql')
  var dtitle = new Array('title1','title2')
  var chart = new Array('chart0', 'chart1')
  for(var i = 0; i < title.length; i++){
    chart[i] = c3.generate({
    bindto : '#chart' + i,
    size: {
           height: 550,
           width: 800
       },
    data : {
     url : '/json/sql/data/test/' + title[i],
     mimeType : 'json',
     type : 'donut'
    },
    donut: {
     title: dtitle[i] + ' - Total:' ,
     label: {
      format: function(value, ratio, id) {
       return value;
      }
     }
    }
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The annoying thing here is that the title option can take a function, but the chart variable is not initialised within it so using the c3 api methods can't be done at this point.

So the best (maybe only) way is to add an onrendered callback that adds up the data as you'd need to anyways and then replace the text in the chart's title text using a spot of d3:

```
onrendered: function () {
    var data = this.api.data();
    var total = data.reduce (function (subtotal, t) {
        return subtotal + t.values.reduce (function (subsubtotal,b) { return subsubtotal + b.value; }, 0);
    }, 0);
    d3.select(this.config.bindto + " .c3-chart-arcs-title").text("Total: "+total);
}
```

Edit: If you want it to keep track of a total as you hide/show series use this

```
var data = this.api.data.shown.call (this.api);
```

instead of

```
var data = this.api.data();
```

Comment: Hey, I have another question. How can I update the total count if i disable a part of the pie?

Comment: The c3 reference is at http://c3js.org/reference.html, but a lot of the stuff we do above isn't documented that well and uses internal c3 methods. If you `console.log(this.api)` in the onrendered methods you can see all the internal c3 properties and how they store the data.